# Video.js is not playing the second time

Tags: javascript, html, video.js, lightgallery

In mobile devices, I want to play the video.js on the first tap. If the user taps again while the video is playing it should open the lightgallery (handleClick).

It is working as expected on first click. But once the video is played, it doesn't play on click afterwards.

The page is also working as expected in desktop devices. On hover the video will play, on click lightgallery will open.

How can I fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link
            href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.3.0/video-js.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.1/css/lightgallery-bundle.min.css"
            integrity="sha512-nUqPe0+ak577sKSMThGcKJauRI7ENhKC2FQAOOmdyCYSrUh0GnwLsZNYqwilpMmplN+3nO3zso8CWUgu33BDag=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        />
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vimeo-player/2.13.0/player.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-gChplnQw7jkk2Axylkdz4PMZCJd5wolmvv3sUZH4m/JrPs1ac5Db7Tms+l1JmZBto6DX8cpE74KTMwS1aOc4bg=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        ></script>
        <title>Video v2</title>
        <style>
            .container {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: auto auto;
                gap: 5rem;
            }

            .column {
                position: relative;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .thumbnail {
                height: 100%;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .thumbnail img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                pointer-events: none;
                z-index: -10;
            }

            .video-container {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                z-index: 10;
            }

            .video-container video {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                pointer-events: none;
                object-fit: cover;
            }
            .player .vp-player-ui-overlays {
                display: none !important;
            }

            @media (max-width: 650px) {
                .container {
                    grid-template-columns: auto;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gallery-videojs-demo" class="container">
            <a
                class="column"
                data-lg-size="1280-720"
                data-video='{"source": [{"src":"https://player.vimeo.com/431680358", "type":"video/mp4"}], "attributes": {"preload": "true", "controls": true}}'
                data-poster="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502613374390-8da7aa532177?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8aW1hZ2VzfGVufDB8fDB8fHww&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                data-sub-html="<h4>'Peck Pocketed' by Kevin Herron | Disney Favorite</h4>"
            >
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img
                        class="img-responsive"
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502613374390-8da7aa532177?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8aW1hZ2VzfGVufDB8fDB8fHww&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="video-container">
                    <video
                        data-src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/431680358.sd.mp4?s=3f97b05e5d5dab21298a96bb5653849567aaf675&profile_id=164&oauth2_token_id=57447761"
                        type="video/mp4"
                    ></video>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a
                class="column"
                data-lg-size="1280-720"
                data-video='{"source": [{"src":"https://player.vimeo.com/503759306", "type":"video/mp4"}], "attributes": {"preload": "true", "controls": true}}'
                data-poster="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591280063444-d3c514eb6e13?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aW1hZ2VzfGVufDB8fDB8fHww&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                data-sub-html="<h4>'Peck Pocketed' by Kevin Herron | Disney Favorite</h4>"
            >
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img
                        class="img-responsive"
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591280063444-d3c514eb6e13?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aW1hZ2VzfGVufDB8fDB8fHww&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="video-container">
                    <video
                        data-src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/503759306.sd.mp4?s=273116dd8b495498766d3fe03e8416fff0cc68b5&profile_id=164&oauth2_token_id=57447761"
                        type="video/mp4"
                    ></video>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.3.0/video.min.js"></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.1/lightgallery.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-dSI4QnNeaXiNEjX2N8bkb16B7aMu/8SI5/rE6NIa3Hr/HnWUO+EAZpizN2JQJrXuvU7z0HTgpBVk/sfGd0oW+w=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.1/plugins/video/lg-video.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-mjdf6tU1Mksu9Hq2YXfbxdzzYHU7SJYmAsMnrhBf80SkHFvk6eHa2d79JM0q5w5ft5nQyBQ0EMB+XTmnvhcFgA=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        ></script>
        <script>
            //open the lightgallery on click
            function handleClick() {
                const clickedElementDataset = event.currentTarget.dataset;

                const galleryData = {
                    dynamic: true,
                    dynamicEl: [
                        {
                            src: clickedElementDataset.video,
                            poster: clickedElementDataset.poster,
                            html: clickedElementDataset.subHtml,
                        },
                    ],
                };

                const lgInstance = lightGallery(
                    document.getElementById("gallery-videojs-demo"),
                    {
                        plugins: [lgVideo],
                        videojs: true,
                        videojsOptions: {
                            muted: true,
                        },
                        ...galleryData,
                    }
                );
                lgInstance.openGallery();
            }

            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                const columns = document.querySelectorAll(".column");

                columns.forEach((column) => {
                    const thumbnail = column.querySelector(".thumbnail");
                    const videoContainer =
                        column.querySelector(".video-container");
                    const video = videoContainer.querySelector("video");
                    let isVideoLoaded = false;

                    video.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
                        videoContainer.style.display = "block";
                        isVideoLoaded = true;
                    });

                    document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);

                    if (window.matchMedia("(hover: hover)").matches) {
                        // Device supports hover (desktop/laptop)
                        column.addEventListener("mouseenter", handleMouseEnter);
                        column.addEventListener("mouseleave", handleMouseLeave);
                        column.addEventListener("click", handleClickInside);
                    } else if (window.matchMedia("(hover: none)").matches) {
                        // Device doesn't support hover (mobile)
                        column.addEventListener("click", () => {
                            // video.paused ? handleMouseEnter() : handleClick();
                            video.paused ? handleMouseEnter() : handleClick();
                        });
                    }

                    async function loadVideoIfNotLoaded() {
                        if (!isVideoLoaded) {
                            await loadVideo();
                        }
                    }

                    async function loadVideo() {
                        const dataSrc = video.getAttribute("data-src");
                        if (dataSrc && !isVideoLoaded) {
                            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                video.src = dataSrc;
                                video.load();
                                video.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
                                    isVideoLoaded = true;
                                    resolve();
                                });
                                video.addEventListener("error", reject);
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    function playVideo() {
                        videoContainer.style.display = "block";
                        player.play();
                    }

                    function handleMouseEnter() {
                        if (!player.paused()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        loadVideoIfNotLoaded()
                            .then(playVideo)
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.error("Error loading video:", error);
                            });
                    }

                    function handleMouseLeave() {
                        player.pause();
                        player.currentTime(0);
                        videoContainer.style.display = "none";
                    }

                    function handleClickOutside(event) {
                        const isClickInsideVideoContainer =
                            event.target.closest(".video-container");
                        const videoContainers =
                            document.querySelectorAll(".video-container");

                        if (!isClickInsideVideoContainer) {
                            videoContainers.forEach((container) => {
                                const video = container.querySelector("video");
                                player.pause();
                                player.currentTime(0);
                                container.style.display = "none";
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    function handleClickInside() {
                        if (!video.paused) {
                            handleClick();
                        }
                    }

                    // Initialize the video player
                    const player = videojs(video, {
                        autoplay: false,
                        muted: true,
                        loop: true,
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

update click listener:

```
column.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (video.paused) {
        handleMouseEnter();
    } else {
        handleClickInside();
    }
});
```

**Second solution:**

update this:

```
column.addEventListener("click", handleClickInside);
```

with:

```
column.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (!player.paused()) {
        handleClick();
    }
});
```

then:

```
function handleClickInside() {
    if (player.paused()) {
        playVideo();
    } else {
        handleClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I've updated the function but still no success. Isn't this just changing the ternary operator to if/else statement?

Comment: Sorry as you have multiple click listeners inside,outide, document etc... I am not sure if all clicks are being handled properly. I added the secod solution try that. If not worked I delete the answer.@RockyBarua